# django celery for long running task

Tags: python, django, django-celery

I have list of players like :

```
player_list = Participant.objects.all()
participant_count = player_list.count()
```

I want to randomly select winner from this like:

```
winner_index = random.randint(0, participant_count-1)
winner = player_list[winner_index]
```

Lets say I have one million participant then I guess It will take long time to randomly generate winner. Till then my site will be hang I guess.

For this purpose should I use celery or its fine? What if my site go hang for few minutes and only display winner. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Why would you think this would take a long time? It's two simple queries, a count and a limit/offset, which any decent database would do in no time at all.

Comment: what if I have millions of players

Comment: Databases are *really good* at things like that, and millions of rows should not be a problem. It's only when you start actually fetching millions of rows of data, or doing complex joins with those large tables, that you should see performance issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With proper indexing your database should be able to handle this without needing any special workarounds. If you make it asynchronous with celery, then you won't be able to include that data in your standard request/response cycle.

If you're worried about page speed for the user, you could load a page without the winner, then do an ajax call using javascript to get the winner and update the page, allowing you to display a loading message to the user while they wait.